# How do I nest devise users with other models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, devise

I just made a new app, and am wondering how I would route it. A user has_many companies,but how how do I route it so? I am using devise.

```
::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users do
    resources :companies
  end

root :to => "home#index"

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest separating between devise routes and other app routes:

```
  devise_for :users, :path => 'accounts'
  resources :users do
    resources :companies
  end
```

This also means that devise will use /accounts/* instead of /users/* for its authentication paths and so /users/* will remain free for your use.

You can also look at devise's [routing documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/frames).

Comment: So now how would I create a show method and view for the users?